# Angular Show Google Analytics dashboard on my site

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I want to find a way of displaying particular user's statistic for his articles. I don’t want to do it myself so I want to find a package which wraps Google Analytics or something else. 
My requirements:

1. It must display statistic for each registered user in the user’s dashboard of my site
2. Users can’t see statistic of each other
3. Statistic must be configurable I don’t want to show much information to users
4. It must have UI: charts and others, and must be easy to built into my site

Answer (score 1):

Found this which is a good attemp to to display the google anayltics in Angular but this is Angular JS (not Angular 2+) -

[Custom Google Analytics dashboard (JavaScript app made with AngularJS, Google Analytics API, D3.js)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pU6pxI-qCnc)

I am also looking to find an existing solution which does the same in Angular 9 or more. Will update if I find something. But this makes a good place to start if you wish to make your own. You can find the code on their [github link](https://github.com/rafcollier/analytics) if you wish to fork out of it.